# Why do we have to explicitly specify the ClassTag typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-reflect

Now that scala has iterated towards a JVM *type erasure* fix with the `ClassTag` typeclass, why is it an opt-in, rather than having the compiler always capture the type signature for runtime inspection. Having it an implicit parametrized type constraint would make it possible to call `classTag[T]` regardless of the generic parameter declaration.

**EDIT**: I should clarify that I don't mean that scala should change the signature behind the scenes to always inlcude `ClassTag`. Rather I mean that since `ClassTag` shows that scala can capture runtime Type information and therefore avoid type erasure limitations, why can't that capture be implicit as part of the compiler so that that information is always available in scala code?

My suspicion is that it's backwards compatibility, java ecosystem compatibility, binary size or runtime overhead related, but those are just speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards compatibility would be completely destroyed, really. If you have a simple method like:

```
def foo[A](a: A)(implicit something: SomeType) = ???
```

Then suppose that in the next version of Scala, the compiler suddenly added implicit `ClassTag`s to the signature of all methods with type parameters. This method would be broken. Anywhere it was being explicitly called like `foo(a)(someTypeValue)` wouldn't work anymore. Binary and source compatibility would be gone.

Java interoperability would be ugly. Supposing our method now looks like this:

```
def foo[A : ClassTag](a: A) = ???
```

Because `ClassTag`s are generated by the Scala compiler, using this method from Java would prove more difficult. You'd have to create the `ClassTag` yourself.

```
ClassTag<MyClass> tag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(MyClass.class);
foo(a, tag);
```

My Java might not be 100% correct, but you get the idea. Anything parameterized would become very ugly. Well, it already is if it requires an implicit `ClassTag`, but the class of methods where this would be necessary would increase dramatically.

Moreover, type erasure isn't *that much of a problem* in most parameterized methods we (I, at least) use. I think automatically requiring a `ClassTag` for each type parameter would be far more trouble than it would help, for the above reasons.

Certainly this would add more compiler overhead, as it would need to generate more `ClassTag`s than it usually would. I don't *think* it would add much more runtime overhead unless the `ClassTag` makes a difference. For example, in a simple method like below, the `ClassTag` doesn't really do anything:

```
def foo[A : ClassTag](a: A): A = a
```

We should also note that they're not perfect, either. So adding them isn't an end-all solution to erasure problems.

```
val list = List(1, "abc", List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b"))
def find[A: ClassTag](l: List[Any]): Option[A] =
    l collectFirst { case a: A => a }

scala> find[List[String]]
res2: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) // Not quite! And no warnings, either.
```

---

Adding a `ClassTag` to every single class instance would add overhead, and surely also break compatibility. It's also in many places not possible. We can't just infuse `java.lang.String` with a `ClassTag`. Furthermore, we'd still be just as susceptible to erasure. Having a `ClassTag` field in each class is really no better than using `getClass`. We *could* make comparisons like

```
case a if(a.getClass == classOf[String]) => a.asInstanceOf[String]
```

But this is horribly ugly, requires a cast, and isn't necessarily what the `ClassTag` is meant to fix. If I tried something like this with my `find` method, it wouldn't work--at all.

```
// Can't compile
def find[A](l: List[Any]): Option[A] =
    l collectFirst { case a if(a.getClass == classOf[A]) => a.asInstanceOf[A] }
```

Even if I were to fashion this to somehow work with `ClassTag`, where would it come from? I *could not* say `a.classTag == classTag[A]`, because `A` has already been erased. I need the `ClassTag` at the method call site.

Comment: I was thinking more of storing the ClassTag implicitly as class meta data available to scala code, rather than actually re-writing the signature to use ClassTag. I suppose it's just my experience with reflection in .NET making me more sensitive to type erasure

Comment: If you store the `ClassTag` in the actual classes though, then we aren't much better off than just using `getClass` and `classOf[A]`. Method type parameters would be harder to recover, because we'd rely on instances that were passed instead of the type parameter itself. My `find` method would never work without an implicit `ClassTag`, because `A` is erased.

Comment: Ah, right. I was imbuing `ClassTag` with more capabilities than it has. It doesn't so much instrument the types in compiled code than pass evidence from the calling instance, which means it's no magic *erasure* cure. Thanks for detailed info

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would penalise any generic method or class for a use case that is quite seldom (e.g. requiring array construction or heterogeneous map value recovery). With this idea of "always class tags" you would also effectively destroy the possibility to call Scala code from Java. In summery, it simply doesn't make any sense to require a class tag to be always present, neither from compatibility, performance or class size point of view.